# How to link HTML drop down list

Tags: php, javascript, html, web

I am basically trying to write a PHP script which will display a message when a certain Option/value is selected in the drop down list.

Here is the html for some clarification

```
 <select name="month">
 <option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">January</option>
<option value="2">Febuary</option>
<option value="3">March</option>
<option value="4">April</option>
</select>
```

Basically, I want the PHP script to print a statement when an option, say the first option (January), is selected.

Comment: This is better done client side, so you should look for a javascript solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably done better on client-side but since you wanted to do it with PHP, here's a simple solution using associative arrays:

**somefile.php**:

```
<?php 
$months = array(1 => 'January', 2 => 'February', 3 => 'March', 4 => 'April', 5 => 'May',
    6 => 'June', 7 => 'July', 8 => 'August', 9 => 'September', 10 => 'October', 11 => 'November',
    12 => 'December');

if(isset($_POST['sb'])){

$input = $_POST['month'];
echo "You selected ".$months[$input];

}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<select name="month">
<option value="1">January</option>
<option value="2">Febuary</option>
<option value="3">March</option>
<option value="4">April</option>
<option value="5">May</option>
<option value="6">June</option>
<option value="7">July</option>
<option value="8">August</option>
<option value="9">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option>

</select>
<input type="submit" name="sb"/>
</form>
```

And if you want to generate your menu dynamically, you could do something like this:

```
<?php
$curr_month = date("m");
$month = array (1=>"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
$select = "<select name=\"month\">\n";
foreach ($month as $key => $val) {
    $select .= "\t<option val=\"".$key."\"";
    if ($key == $curr_month) {
        $select .= " selected=\"selected\">".$val."</option>\n";
    } else {
        $select .= ">".$val."</option>\n";
    }
}
$select .= "</select>";
echo $select;
?>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

If you want the action to take place when the select is changed you need a client side solution like javascript, preferably jQuery.

PHP cannot do what you asking, it can do something when the form is submitted but not when the select is changed.

http://api.jquery.com/change/

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").on("change", function(){
         alert("The value is " + $(this).val());
    });
});
```

That will produce an alert when your select is changed.

Comment: OP want the PHP script not js

Comment: OP may want, but they cannot have. *when an option ..... is selected*, that cannot be done with PHP. It can be done when a form *is submitted*, but not when the drop down is selected.

Comment: Not to mention, the server doesn't need to see a display message, whereas the _client_ does.

Comment: @jakenoble I think you need to explain it much more and add some more code.

Answer (score 0):

That's not something that can be done with PHP. PHP is executed server-side, meaning it delivers a static page once all the server-side processing has been completed. To change something, it would have to be submitted back to the server and redelivered.

Javascript is what you'll want to use here. Check out the Codecademy jQuery track, it's really helpful for figuring out how to do client-side work the way you want. http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/jquery

Basically you'd want to have an `onchange="function()"` attribute for the select, which would call a javascript function to display a message in a separate area.

For example (not quite what you want but illustrates the principle:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var changed = function() {
        alert("Value of select is now: " + event.target.value);
    };
</script>

<form action="index.php" method="POST"> 
  <select name="month" onchange="changed()">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">Febuary</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
    <option value="4">April</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

If your html looks like this:

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST"> 
  <select name="month">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">Febuary</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
    <option value="4">April</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Select">
</form>
```

Then in your index.php:

```
echo "You selected " . $_POST['month'];
```

Comment: That will not work. There is no submit button and it will not do what the OP asked, which is *on select* not *on submit*